# Retrieve a List of Application Versions

Tags: android-versions

I want to retrieve a list of installed applications on KitKat and I also need their version numbers. I know I can use adb shell pm . . . to obtain a list of all packages, but I need the version for each application. I want to use ADB instead of manually clicking on each app inside of app manager. Is there a command that will give me that information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

In ADB shell issue the following command:

```
dumpsys package packages
```

This gives you all the information about installed packages, including the version number. You can then play around with `grep` utility to narrow down the results to only the lines you need:

```
dumpsys package packages | grep -E 'Package \[|versionName'
```

The above returns something similar to this:

```
Package [com.android.voicedialer] (41cb1a08):
versionName=4.4.2-323cb6b305
Package [com.android.defcontainer] (41cb4750):
versionName=4.4.2-323cb6b305
Package [ru.ok.android] (41cb7200):
versionName=3.7.5
Package [org.koxx.pure_calendar] (41cb9818):
versionName=3.3.3
Package [com.android.phone] (41df4fe8):
versionName=4.4.2-323cb6b305
Package [com.gsamlabs.xposed.mods.enablebatterystatspermission] (41cbc008):
versionName=1.2
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this app from Google Play:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.ox.AppList&hl=en

Description:
Write down all installed applications into the text or html file and save it on memory card into the InstalledApps directory.
In default, it creats log after each installed/uninstalled application.
Check Setup button in application for more settings.
Basic PHP script for auto upload you can find at http://www.2ox.cz/applist/

I am not author of this app.